# Moving Smartphone Camera around three.js Object

Tags: angular, three.js, camera, augmented-reality, gyroscope

I  have a simple rectangle which I have placed on my camera preview. I want to simulate an AR effect. When my camera moves, I don’t want the rectangle to move with it, but to stay fixed in position. I know that I have to access the gyroscope of my smartphone, but I don’t know how this works and how I have to connect these coordinates to the 3D camera. I program with Angular.

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );
    camera.position.z = 5;
    const animate = () => {
            cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
};
animate();
```

I know that my animation is messed up, but this is not imporant. It is important for me to get the rotation trough moving the camera.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to enable the XR in the renderer first.

`renderer.xr.enabled = true;`

I would suggest you look into the example called webxr_ar_hittest in this [Github repository](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples).